# Proving $d$ is a metric on $X$ from the given properties of $d$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

**Q.** Let $X$ be a non-empty set and $d\colon X\times X\to\Bbb R$ be a function satisfying the following two conditions:

i) $d(x,y)=0\iff x=y$

ii) $d(x,y)\leq d(x,z)+d(y,z)~~\forall~x,y,z\in X$. Prove that $d$ is a metric on $X$.

---

**My attempt:**

Till now, I have shown that $d(x,y)\geq 0~\forall~x,y\in X$ but I'm stuck at showing symmetry. Here's what I did:

Setting $y=x$ in (ii), we get $2d(x,z)\geq d(x,x)=0\implies d(x,z)\geq 0~\forall~x,y,z\in X$. Since $z$ is an arbitrary element of $X$, we can replace it with $y$ which is also an arbitrary element of $X$ and conclude that $d(x,y)\geq 0~\forall~x,y\in X$. This along with (i) shows that $d$ is non-negative and satisfies the identity of indiscernibles.

Now, setting $z=x$ in (ii), we get, $$d(x,y)\leq d(x,x)+d(y,x)\implies d(x,y)\leq d(y,x)~\forall~x,y,z\in X$$

I'm stuck at showing $d(y,x)\leq d(x,y)$ which would allow me to conclude that $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$, i.e., $d$ is symmetric.

I can see that if I prove that $d$ is symmetric, the triangle inequality follows trivially from (ii) and $d(y,z)=d(z,y)$ and the proof that $d$ is a metric on $X$ is done.

Can someone help me with the symmetry part? Thanks in advance!

Comment: $d(y,x) \le d(y,y) +  d(x,y) \implies d(y,x) \le d(x,y)$

Comment: The symbols $x,y,z$ are quite arbitrary. You've shown $d(x,y)\leq d(y,x)$ for all $x,y$. Just change the variables, if you wish: $d(\alpha,\beta)\leq d(\beta,\alpha)$ for all $\alpha,\beta$. Now change variables again, by $\alpha=y$, $\beta=x$ and you obtain $d(y,x)\leq d(x,y)$ for all $x,y$.

Comment: Just do it twice:  $d(x,y) <= d(x,x) + d(y,x) = d(y,x)$ and $d(y,x) < = d(y,y) + d(x,y) = d(x,y)$.  So $d(x,y) < = d(y,x)$ and $d(y,x) <= d(x,y)$ so $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Simply let $z=y$ and apply the same method you used to prove the other direction, reversing the order of $x,y$.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $a, b \in X$.

Let $x=a, y=b, z=a$. We have

$$d(a, b) \leq d(a, a) + d(b, a) = d(b, a)$$

On the other hand, put $x=b, y=a, z = b$. We have

$$d(b, a) \leq d(a, b) + d(b, b) = d(a, b)$$

and thus $d(a, b) = d(b, a)$.

Answer (score 0):

It's only a notational problem.

Fix $x_0,y_0\in X$. Then you have already shown that $\forall x,y\in X,d(x,y)\leq d(y,x)$ (*).

We apply it to $x=y_0$ and $y=x_0$ (why not? It's true *for all* $x,y\in X$) and we obtain:
$$d(y_0,x_0)\leq d(x_0,y_0)$$

We apply (*) to $x=x_0$ and $y=y_0$ and we have:
$$d(x_0,y_0)\leq d(y_0,x_0)$$

Now, everything above didn't depend on the particular values of $x_0$ and $y_0$ so that 
$$\forall x_0,y_0\in X,\;d(x_0,y_0)=d(y_0,x_0)$$